# How to make Javascript array unique by attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is a fast way of making a Javascript array unique by attribute?

I have an array sorted by timestamp, like this:

```
[
    {
        ts: 1417048100,
        release: 1.0
    },
    {
        ts: 1417046900,
        release: 1.1
    },
    {
        ts: 1417046712,
        release: 1.0
    }
]
```

And I want to make it unique by release number, keeping only the ones with the latest timestamp. In my example, that would mean removing the last entry since there is a newer one for that release.

Comment: One way could be to sort by release and ts and then filter, keeping only the first object in a sequence of objects with the same release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the array with `forEach` and store the release numbers in an object to make sure that any releases already iterated over are spliced out of the array.

```js
var arr = [{
    ts: 1417048100,
    release: 1.0
},
{
    ts: 1417046900,
    release: 1.1
},
{
    ts: 1417046712,
    release: 1.0
}];

var o = {};

arr.forEach(function(x, i) {
    if (x.release in o) arr.splice(i, 1);
    o[x.release] = null; 
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a mapping, using the `release` as the key.

```
var output = {};
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
  output[input[i].release] = input[i].ts;
}
```

It will automatically overwrite older release keys with newer release keys.

If you need it to remain sorted, then you would need to re-convert it to a list and sort it, or filter the original list down by only the remaining output keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Array.prototype.reduce** along with **Array.prototype.some** like:

```js
var items = [{ts: 1417048100,release: 1.0},{ts: 1417046900,release: 1.1},{ts: 1417046712,release: 1.0}];

var results = items.reduce(function(res, item){
var exists = res.some(function(t){ return (t.release === item.release );});        
     if (!exists){
        res.push(item);
     }
return res; },[]);
                                                                              document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(results) + '</pre>';
```

**Array.prototype.some** allows you to check whether or not the item exists in the array and if it does it is not  included in the **Array.prototype.reduce**  `res.push(item);` while processing of the array.

If you are open to use other libraries you may be interested in checking lo-dash unique:

https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jquery then try with grep

```
var releases =[
    {
    ts: 1417048100,
    release: 1.0
    },
    {
        ts: 1417046900,
        release: 1.1
    },
    {
        ts: 1417046712,
        release: 1.0
    }];

    var newRelease={
        ts: 1517046712,
        release: 1.0
    };

releases = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) {
  return value.release != newRelease.release;
});

releases.push(newRelease);
```

Comment: You need to compare `value.release` to `newRelease.release`. Plus, this doesn't remove the entry if it is newer than what you compare against.

Comment: i assumed the new ts will be greater than the old one, if not the OP should check converting the ts to js datetime object

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var arr = [
  {
    ts: 1417048100,
    release: 1.0
  },
  {
    ts: 1417046900,
    release: 1.1
  },
  {
    ts: 1417046712,
    release: 1.0
  }
]

, arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.ts > b.ts) ? -1 : 1
}).filter(function(val, key) {
  return $.inArray(val.release, arr.map(function(v) {return v.release})) === key
});
```

```js
    var arr = [
      {
        ts: 1417048100,
        release: 1.0
      },
      {
        ts: 1417046900,
        release: 1.1
      },
      {
        ts: 1417046712,
        release: 1.0
      }
    ]

    , arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (a.ts > b.ts) ? -1 : 1
    }).filter(function(val, key) {
      return $.inArray(val.release, arr.map(function(v) {return v.release})) === key
    });

    $.each(arr, function(k, v) {
      $("<span>").html("release:" + v.release + ", timestamp:" + v.ts + "<br />")
      .appendTo("body")
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the array into an associative array. The keys in an associative array are unique. 
Example code shown in node.

```
→ node
> a ={ "1.0": 1417048100, "1.1": 1417046900}
{ '1.0': 1417048100,
  '1.1': 1417046900 }
> a["1.0"]
1417048100
> a["1.0"]=99999
99999
> a
{ '1.0': 99999,
  '1.1': 1417046900 }
```

For a better understanding read up on hashes and the blog post below may also be helpful.

http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/03/29/how-to-use-javascript-hashes/